# Grails automatically creating unwanted relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes specifying three levels of categorization.

```
class CategoryGroup {
    String name
    static hasMany = [categories:Category]   
}


class Category {
    String name
    Category topCategory = null
    Set<Category> subCategories

    static mappedBy = [subCategories:'topCategory',topCategory:'subCategories']
    static hasMany = [subCategories:Category, categoryGroups:CategoryGroup]
    static belongsTo = [CategoryGroup]
}
```

`CategoryGroup` is the highest level, then each `CategoryGroup` has many `categories` (and each `Category` can be under many `CategoryGroup`). Also each `Category` has many `subCategories`. A category can be identified as a subcategory if `topCategory` holds it's parent category.

Now here's the problemo.

I create two `CategoryGroup`s: Men's and Women's
Then I create a `Category`: Clothing, and place it under both Men's and Women's
Now I create two more Categories - Boxers and Sarees, and make them as subcategories of Clothing, only that Boxers is placed under `CategoryGroup` Men's and Sarees is placed under `CategoryGroup` Women's.

What I want is that when I select Men's, and then I select Clothing, only SubCategories under Clothing that belong to parent category Men's should appear (ie only Boxers and not Sarees)

But when I do this, Boxers is getting added automatically to Women's! That is, when i do `boxers.categoryGroups.name`, i see both Men's and Women's.

How can this happen?

Comment: Can you make sure that you're creating separate instances of 'Clothing' category for each group and that there are two records of 'Clothing' in your Category table?

Comment: there is only one instance of Clothing... am i supposed to make two? (Category name is unique by the way)

Comment: Yes you need to make two instances of the 'Clothing' category. Your subcategories 'Boxers' and 'Sarees' are mapped to 'Clothing' not to 'Mens' or 'Womens'.

Comment: is there no way we can keep the category common? this is a requirement.

Comment: Only if you change your relationships. E.g. No relationship between "Men's" and "Clothing". "Boxers" are mapped to "Men's" and also mapped to "Clothing". That way you can find all the categories in the "Men's" group and filter by the topCategory (= "Clothing").

Comment: Draw the object's relationships on a sheet of paper. You'll see why cannot a single instance solve that.

Comment: ok thanks all for the help